# TS incorrectly inferring intersection type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

We hit a TS error that we weren't able to resolve, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it. TS seems to infer a an intersection type on `combo.input`, which seems odd (a union type makes more sense to me).

I boiled down an example below.

We ended up just using a different method, but I feel there should be a way to type the functions to fix the error.

```
const stringFunc = (input: string): string => input;
const numFunc = (input: number): number => input;

const stringCombo = { funct: stringFunc, input: 'hello' };
const numCombo = { funct: numFunc, input: 4 };

type Combo = typeof stringCombo | typeof numCombo;

const processCombo = (combo: Combo) => {
  return combo.funct(combo.input);  
     // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of answer by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir,
you could also model your types as generics:

```ts
type FunTtoT<T> = (t: T) => T;

const stringFunc: FunTtoT<string> = (input: string): string => input;
const numFunc: FunTtoT<number> = (input: number): number => input;

type Combo<T extends string | number> =  { funct: FunTtoT<T>, input: T };

const stringCombo = { funct: stringFunc, input: 'hello' };
const numCombo = { funct: numFunc, input: 4 };

function processCombo<T extends string | number>(combo: Combo<T>) {
  return combo.funct(combo.input);  
};

const s = processCombo(stringCombo);  // inferred to string
const n = processCombo(numCombo);     // inferred to number
```

I prefer this approach both to discriminated union and type assertion, as the output type is inferred to a single type, not to an union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwCrAPZIDxIHxQLxQAUwAXFEgJT65IDcAUPQMaoIDOwUHATgJYIBzeAiZlhKdBh78BuAoX5g4pLsD6CKZaYOpRFyhi3acEcALbDRsRBMymzAIwjc5RfSvtPumqJ+e73BnpQSCgAYVRHVCwoCAAPYAgEABM2VXUBKAAfX3MvVygAbygAM0QmFXE0TBwAGj0EJRUkKABfIKMOdJkIqPwi0vKVbSFy+vcyAHIACwgAGznUSbbDVi77XodUfuKykQ9zS3HG5TIAFhXGPYreVigwblQmCDY2TeiW+MSUtJHs3MczmwhBYUTI7yw2CohXoUCg3AgwDg3AQUFBWwAdNdgCDIpj3BRaHD6O1GJ1OGkCA8ni83njUIQRu9Ccw1iZ+tTnq93oQNvTCUA)

Comment: Thanks! I need to play around with this, but it seems to be the closest to "best practice". I'm gonna plug this into my React example and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

This is not wrong, more a design limitation. `combo.funct` is a union of functions. This means that it can be a either a function that accepts a `string` or a function that accepts a `number`, but at the the time of the call there is no way to know which it is. Consequently the only safe way to call `combo.funct` is with a parameter that can satisfy BOTH function signatures. In this case that type would be `number & string` which reduces to `never` (if these were functions accepting different object types, there could be a value that satisfies both object types)

In this particular case the function and the argument are actually corelated, but typescript doesn't track this. All it can see is that the type of `combo.input` (which is `string | number`) does not work as am argument for the union of functions `combo.funct`.

You could use a discriminated union:

```
const stringFunc = (input: string): string => input;
const numFunc = (input: number): number => input;

const stringCombo = { funct: stringFunc, input: 'hello', type: "string" as const };
const numCombo = { funct: numFunc, input: 4 , type: "number" as const};

type Combo = typeof stringCombo | typeof numCombo;

const processCombo = (combo: Combo) => {
  return combo.type === "string"?
      combo.funct(combo.input):
      combo.funct(combo.input);
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAYgVzMGBeGAFMgA4ZQBccUSqAlJQsingHwwlkDcAsAFCiRYYDAFtM2PIQ4UYwkQCMApvHqzRS+K3ZhSUHrz4DoVGigDCIBSEkBvGADMswGY1TjgAGm27KAcgAWigA2QSC+XlAAnsSKlABErihxMACGEDBGsAC++plqIhZWtg5OMnLuXtKUACwwEdGxMHFyGslpGeDQOXx8UTEwhfLW+H2KIPYmTIPWAD4wo+P50-qGnbDE8CDAihAQ05IEoFaU07RaNnwwMPCKUBjwYB1WAHSjeLj4CdRMcQD8l1dAUchs9HNgoIdLCDpPQAYCniCwc5IS8YfpurwgA)

Or since this a case where we clearly know more than the compiler we can use a type assertion:

```
const processCombo = (combo: Combo) => {
  return combo.funct(combo.input as never);  
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAYgVzMGBeGAFMgA4ZQBccUSqAlJQsingHwwlkDcAsAFCiRYYDAFtM2PIQ4UYwkQCMApvHqzRS+K3ZhSUHrz4DoVGigDCIBSEkBvGADMswGY1TjgAGm27KAcgAWigA2QSC+MAC++kZCohZWtg5OMnLuXtKUACyR+nxQAJ7EijDx8tb4BUUg9iZMpdYAPjCVitVqIvW5-ODGxPAgwIoQEPWSBKBWlPW0WjZ8MDDwilAY8GAwE2UAdI7YUOOW29IwAIYQsooAbsq0nAt8UUA)

Comment: Thanks! I knew a discriminated union would work, but wanted to avoid it.

I like `as never` as a solution though.

The working example ended up with a fairly complex intersection type here, but that is at least creatable.